# Splitting the string in group of two or three words

Tags: java, string, recursion, dynamic-programming

given a string, we have to split the string in all distinct two and three parts (permutation doesn't matter).
for example
for:

```
cat
```

answer is

```
ca t
ct a
c at
c a t
```

for

```
aaa
```

answer is

```
aa a
a a a
```

how to do that?
can you please provide a code in the best possible time complexity?

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Note that the meta link above is not *just*  about homework. It is really about >any< programming problem: homework, self learning or even some IT problem at work that you don't have the skills to tackle. If you don't try, you won't learn

Comment: this is not a homework problem

Comment: Please read what I wrote.  *"Note that the meta link above **is not just about homework**. It is really about >any< programming problem: homework, self learning or even some IT problem at work that you don't have the skills to tackle. If you don't try, you won't learn ".*

Comment: Also, please don't assume that people who are voting to close your questions don't know the answer.  The real reason they are voting to close is that the question is not appropriate.  Read the link!  (I could and would post an answer ... *if I thought that the question was properly asked*.  But posting a problem with no attempt to solve it is treating SO as a "write code for me for free" service.  That is not what it is here for.)

Comment: you know it's tough, I didn't find its solution anywhere... if you could help, please try man.

Comment: why it is happening here that repeated questions are being answered for which the solutions are present everywhere, but new question is never answered here.

Comment: You shouldn't be looking for solutions.  You should be trying to write your own solutions.  Seriously, programming is something you will only learn by **doing it**.   (I'm not going to answer your "why is it" question.  Except to say that the world and people are inconsistent, and I can't explain that.)

Comment: I'm only asking here because I can't try. if I have tried, I would have surely solved it myself.

Comment: Well ... if you have tried, then you show us what you have done.  And if you "can't try" ... you need to take a programming course ... so that someone can teach you.

Answer (score 0):

So i wrote a code for your problem, I wrote this code especially for string containing 3 characters. This code is nothing just "System.out.println" written in different style, if this doesn't suit you please provide me more input i would like it to solve then.`
public void checkString(String s) {
String strArry[] = s.split("");

```
    if (strArry[0].equalsIgnoreCase(strArry[1])) {
        System.out.println(strArry[0] + strArry[1] + " " + strArry[2]);
        System.out.println(strArry[0] + " " + strArry[1] + " " + strArry[2]);

    } else {
        {
            System.out.println(strArry[0] + strArry[1] + " " + strArry[2]);
            System.out.println(strArry[0] + strArry[2] + " " + strArry[1]);
            System.out.println(strArry[0] + " " + strArry[1] + strArry[2]);
            System.out.println(strArry[0] + " " + strArry[1] + " " + strArry[2]);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: the string can be up to length 10